# most karaoke songs are too high for me to sing

Tags: voice, vocal-range, voice-training, voice-change

i am an untrained singer, and i did many tests in the youtube videos to check my vocal range.. i can hit (not necessary sing with confidence) the g2 - g#4.

is it normal it i cannot sing most of the karaoke songs i want?

and what if i will take vocal teacher and do exercises, will i be able to sing most of the songs?

it feels like all the karaoke songs are made for trained tenors who can easily reach high notes.. is that the case? or m I just a baritone?

Comment: Some karaoke players have pitch shifting facilities which allow you to lower the key a few steps.

Comment: well... i mostly song in hebrew and i didnt find this feature yet.. and its not about being able to sing karaoke, more about know what is common..

Comment: I can’t sing most of a karaoke songs I want. I’ve noticed that popular songs often have high voices, and popular bands often have singers with high voices. If you find a good voice teacher, you can definitely extend your range. You can also help your voice last for most of your life. Looking back, I wish I’d had voice lessons when I was young.

Comment: You could always just sing an octave lower

Comment: @dissemin8or i dont see how excactly that can solve anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any access to your head voice? You may very well be a baritone who cannot push his chest voice higher than g#4, but switching to head voice could open up a few more notes and allow you to sing more songs (though not necessarily with the power that a natural tenor would achieve).

A good teacher and lots of practive can most likely help you with developing your head voice.

Comment: wha t do you mean by accessing head voice? i can sing head voice but it sounds silly..  i can reach way higher notes with head voice... and i saw that average untrained tenor ( in this site ) is A2-Ab4(g#4 is the same, right?) it seems most likely that i am just untrained tenor... i actually can reach even A4 sometimes on singing...

Comment: when i see youtube performance of people singing high, does that mean that they are trained tenors ? or untrained tenors and i am just in an illusion thay i am untrained tenor?

Comment: It doesn't really matter that much whether you "are" a tenor or a baritone (from the ranges you give, I'd assume you're more in the baritone category) - you're unhappy with the high notes you can reach in chest voice, and you can reach them in falsetto but it doesn't sound good. Improving the transition between chest and head voice is precisely the thing a good vocal teacher can help you with, so find one and see where it leads you. Also, when you see people doing impressive things on Youtube, it's quite likely they trained quite a bit.

Comment: I am willing to take a voice teacher, but I also like to learn some stuff by myself. and it doesnt matter the labeling, i agree.. but does it matter to know the potential range? , and should I focus on high notes vs low notes and strong resonance?

Comment: I've seen different values given for the range of a baritone, with upper limits from D4 to A4... and that's not surprising, because it's an arbitrary line between "guys with a high voice" and "guys with a not-so-high voice", not a natural category. Again: if you're unhappy with the high notes you can hit, practice high notes: practice frontal resonance, practice switching/ sliding between your chest and head voice. Maybe you can learn to extend your chest voice a few more notes, maybe you can get your head voice to the point where you can use it without embarrassment.

Comment: thanks alot, After reading it many time and more information in the internet, i have a better understanding and i really appreciate your answer and explanation!